# NCCL install / Tensorflow complie error with RTX 2080ti

Tags: python, python-2.7, tensorflow

I am installing Cuda 10, CuDnn 7.3 and NCCL 2.3 on Ubuntu 18.04 with a 2080ti. I am having trouble with the NCCL part. When i try to compile Tensorflow it says error and cannot find NCCL-SLA.txt file. But when i search for that file i cant find it anywhere either? So when i look online people say you can move it from another directory but its not there for me so i do not know what to do.

Here is the error code i am getting:

```
ERROR: missing input file '@local_config_nccl//:nccl/NCCL-SLA.txt'
ERROR: /home/josh/tensorflow/tensorflow/tools/pip_package/BUILD:166:1: //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package: missing input file '@local_config_nccl//:nccl/NCCL-SLA.txt'
Target //tensorflow/tools/pip_package:build_pip_package failed to build
Use --verbose_failures to see the command lines of failed build steps.
ERROR: /home/josh/tensorflow/tensorflow/tools/pip_package/BUILD:166:1 1 input file(s) do not exist
INFO: Elapsed time: 17.209s, Critical Path: 11.30s
INFO: 353 processes, local.
FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully
```

Comment: Maybe this will help you -  https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/19679

Comment: thanks matt yes i was just reading that but the solution of moving the .txt file does not work for me as i do not have that file. I cannot find it anywhere they say it is on that post and the solution posted of comping from source did not work either. If you have any ideas please let me know

Comment: do you have a file called LICENCE.txt?

Comment: yes in the place i installed nccl it is there but the error is asking for NCCL-SLA.txt not LISCENSE .txt right?

Comment: try copy LICENSE.txt to  NCCL-SLA.txt (in the same directory)

Comment: just tried that and it didn't work..

Comment: Just tried again and it works thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you can’t find the file NCCL-SLA.txt, try copy the file LICENSE.txt to a new file named NCCL-SLA.txt in the same directory